# Shellac, Texture, and Smoke Damage

Tags: drywall, painting

We have a 4-plex that started on fire. The sheetrock in a couple of units was saved. To lock in the smoke odor, we were told we need to use a shellac primer. However, we would like to texture the walls. Should I apply the shellac first, then texture, prime, and paint or can I texture the walls first, shellac, then paint? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, as with new drywall, the drywall is primed before applying texture.  Priming allows for even, proper drying of the texture.  Shellac would do the same thing.  So I would shellac, texture, prime, paint.

Comment: Please make sure your wall are clean first. The soot from the smoke would hinder any kind of paint or primer from adhering properly. As in any good paint job, preparation is half, if not more, of the job.